# Merge two columns into new columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have create a new column of type `varchar(30)` to store a result of concatenation of two exist columns in the same table.

I am trying to write a query to do that

Here is my table

```
ID   COLUMN1   COLUMN2 
-----------------------
1    US        TEXAS
2    JAPAN     TOKYO
```

I Want the result to be stored in the exist table.

```
ID   COLUMN1   COLUMN2   FULL_ADDRESS
-------------------------------------
1    US        TEXAS     US TEXAS
2    JAPAN     TOKYO     JAPAN TOKYO
```

Here's my attempt:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl 
    SET FULL_ADDRESS = COLUMN1 + '' + COLUMN2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`computed column`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD FULL_ADDRESS AS (COLUMN1+' '+COLUMN2);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/UTQM72589)**

Answer (score 2):

To physically store the concatenated data, I would use a computed column that is persisted. e.g. in SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl 
    ADD FullAddress AS CONCAT(Column1, ' ', Column2) PERSISTED
```

`Persisted` also means you can build an index on `FullAddress` if you need to help with query performance.